# Chart.js random rgb background color generator not working

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am attempting to create a system that generates random RGB values within a range to use as the background color for that specific point of data. Currently, Chart.js only uses specified background values for each piece of data and does not automatically generate values for each data-point.

What I tried to do is create a system that randomly generates an RGB value for each piece of data, adds it to a list of those color values, and then uses that list in place of the hard-coded data.

The colors don't seem to be showing up when I open the page.

Any help?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("centerPie");

var internalData = [300, 50, 100, 75];

var graphColors = [];
var graphOutlines = [];
var hoverColor = [];

var internalDataLength = internalData.length;
i = 0;
while (i <= internalDataLength, i++) {
    var randomR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
    var randomG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
    var randomB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
   
    var graphBackground = "rgb(" 
            + randomR + ", " 
            + randomG + ", " 
            + randomB + ")";
    graphColors.push(graphBackground);
    
    var graphOutline = "rgb(" 
            + (randomR - 80) + ", " 
            + (randomG - 80) + ", " 
            + (randomB - 80) + ")";
    graphOutlines.push(graphOutline);
    
    var hoverColors = "rgb(" 
            + (randomR + 25) + ", " 
            + (randomG + 25) + ", " 
            + (randomB + 25) + ")";
    hoverColor.push(hoverColors);
    
};


var data = {
    labels: [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four"
    ],
    datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100, 75],
            backgroundColor: graphColors,
            hoverBackgroundColor: hoverColor,
            borderColor: graphOutlines
    }]
};

var options = {
    cutoutPercentage: 25,
    responsive: true
    
};



var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options,
    animation: {
        animateRotate:true
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/widthCalculator.js"></script>
    <div class="app container-fluid">
        <div id="header">
            <table>
                <td class="header-left"><img class="menu" src="img/menu-icon.png" alt="menu" height="30" width="30" /></td>
                <td class="header-right"><h2>Title Here</h2></td>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="header-holder"></div>
        <div class="row top-body">
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
                <canvas id="centerPie" width="10" height="10"></canvas>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/mainChart.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-5'>
                <p>:o</p>
                <p>:o</p>
                <p>:o</p>
                <p>:o</p>
                <p>:o</p>
                <p>:o</p>
                <p>:o</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
        <p>:o</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I also modified the borders and hover colors with slight variations in the color for aesthetic appeal (reason for such limited range of values in RGB)

Thank you!

Comment: Also please note that you'll get a better response if you cut down your code to just the minimum to duplicate the problem. There's a lot of unnecessary html included above

Comment: of course, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change how you're incrementing `i` in your `while` loop:

```
while (i <= internalDataLength) {
  ...    
  i++;
};
```

NB: there's a chart library error in the following snippet, but the colours are now showing

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("centerPie");

var internalData = [300, 50, 100, 75];

var graphColors = [];
var graphOutlines = [];
var hoverColor = [];

var internalDataLength = internalData.length;
i = 0;
while (i <= internalDataLength) {
    var randomR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
    var randomG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
    var randomB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 130) + 100);
  
    var graphBackground = "rgb(" 
            + randomR + ", " 
            + randomG + ", " 
            + randomB + ")";
    graphColors.push(graphBackground);
    
    var graphOutline = "rgb(" 
            + (randomR - 80) + ", " 
            + (randomG - 80) + ", " 
            + (randomB - 80) + ")";
    graphOutlines.push(graphOutline);
    
    var hoverColors = "rgb(" 
            + (randomR + 25) + ", " 
            + (randomG + 25) + ", " 
            + (randomB + 25) + ")";
    hoverColor.push(hoverColors);
    
  i++;
};


var data = {
    labels: [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four"
    ],
    datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100, 75],
            backgroundColor: graphColors,
            hoverBackgroundColor: hoverColor,
            borderColor: graphOutlines
    }]
};

var options = {
    cutoutPercentage: 25,
    responsive: true
    
};



var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options,
    animation: {
        animateRotate:true
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="app container-fluid">
  <div id="header-holder"></div>
  <div class="row top-body">
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
      <canvas id="centerPie" width="10" height="10"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you good sir! This works like a charm (though i should opt to not let it show barf green as a color haha)